# Parse xml data efficiently python using iterfind

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I am parsing lots of repeating data from a large XML file(10MB), and then over 100,000 of these files. I want to make sure I'm parsing efficiently. First I make a list of all the Element paths I want to find. This might be 100-200 different elements, then I want to find them all and store them in a dictionary key'd by the element name.

I've been using iterfind('/elementpath/'), but that returns a generator that I then have to iterate through again to get the text in each of the elements. This 2nd loop is what I'm trying to eliminate

Here is some code that does what I want as best I can optimize it. It takes around 2 sec per file to parse the data. If I can remove the nested loop having then that improves to 1.2 ms or so.

```
def parse_xml(testfile):
    resultdict={}
    for search in searchlist:
        resultdict[search]=[]
        for item in testfile.iterfind(search):
            resultdict[search].append(item.text)
    return resultdict
```

Comment: `for search in searchlist: resultdict[search].extend(item.text for item in testfile.iterfind(search))`

Comment: depends on your search criteria, you can `resultdict[search] = testfile.xpath(search + '/text()')`.